# Are all vector bundles "flat vector bundles"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology

This concept appears in Bott&Tu's GTM82. A flat vector bundle is one who has a particular trivialization with locally constant transition functions. Then my question is whether every vector bundle over a manifold admits such a trivialization.

btw: Are the tags correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  Using the Chern-Weil perspective on characteristic classes (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern-Weil_theory)), you can prove that all the rational Pontryagin classes of a flat vector bundle have to vanish.  Thus all you need are vector bundles with non-vanishing rational Pontryagin classes, of which there are many.

A very nice source for this perspective on characteristic classes and flat bundles is Morita's book "[Geometry of characteristic classes](http://books.google.com/books?id=EUQhXDTI_mUC)".

Comment: I tried to put a link to wikipedia, but it seems to have been deleted...

Comment: I fixed it. Wikipedia has [this habit](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017/link-copying-causes-misinterpretation-in-mark-down-in-comments) of using non-standard characters in links, and that is not very well supported by this site. Here it was the dash. Replacing it by the the dash on the keyboard usually works, otherwise you have to resort to [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) but that is somewhat painful.

Comment: @Adam Smith a very minor point : there is no "The" in the title of Morita's book.

Comment: In particular, the tangent bundle of $S^2$ can't be given a flat structure.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I'll check these material out.